# How to send data from server to android application to specific USER and to GROUP

Tags: android

I want make an android application in which admin sends message from server.admin can select whom to send e.g. Specific User **or** All User Of Some Department **or** To All.i am thinking of **google cloud messaging**.i want solutions how it will be done.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you MarvinLabs for wasting time in commenting and not helping.i want how to approach to this scenario not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,  exectly GCM is the greatest way for this requirement. Read this document with concentrate and you will achieve you goal. Because i have experienced with GCM : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Also lets have look with this video it also more help full to you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM

Comment: Thank u Himanshu for your Help